# Graph theory - when all edges of a node are contained within a cycle

Tags: python, graph, graph-theory, combinatorics, graph-traversal

Given a directed or undirected graph, there are many algorithms to find cycles.  However, I am looking for a specific type of cycle.  A cycle in which a node [0...n] in my graph, which has "k" outward edges, has all k of it's edges contained to that cycle.  That is to say, all of the edges of our node only connect to other nodes that make up the cycle.

Example:

We have a cycle (in an undirected graph, this time): A-B-D-E-C-A

In my matrix, node B has the following edges:

B-A,
B-E,
B-D

This cycle qualifies as the type of feature I am looking for.

It is not required that *every* node in the cycle meet this rule- it is only required that *at least* one node in the cycle meets the rule.

So my question is - is there a name for this type of feature?  And, is there an algorithm or does anyone even have a suspicion that an algorithm could be made to find such features more efficiently than randomly searching for cycles and then checking if any of their nodes meet the rule?

Comment: Would you mind sharing why such a node would be special? I don't have an answer, but I'm just curious about your use-case.

Comment: I am not very comfortable withholding information, but I honestly think my idea would be liable to be stolen before I could publish anything on it.  It does have a use, and if I could find a more efficient way to find this feature than I currently have, it's use could be important.

Comment: Fair enough. It sounded interesting, which is why I was curious :)

Comment: I *suspect* that you can make a table of nodes that are not connected to anything during your cycle finding algorithm and update that as you go. I suspect that won't cost you anything in complexity.

Comment: If your use-case is important enough, perhaps you will be able to coin the term for these nodes or cycles. Perhaps it will be a Black Cycle or a Travis Node one day. Good luck.

Comment: hehe thank you that is very kind of you

Comment: So you are OK with all the nodes in the cycle connecting elsewhere as long as there is one node that only connects within the cycle?

Comment: yes exactly.  and it's also fine (great actually) for more than one to only connect within the cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the cycles in a component of a graph by doing a DFS and finding all back edges (e.g. [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/)). This is an `O(n + m)` operation.

In the worst case, you could build a hash table (set) of all the nodes in the cycle and just check the connections of every node against it. There is no additional cost to building the hash table in terms of complexity, since you can do it while you unwind the stack that created the cycle and insertions are O(1), but checking against it may be expensive since the number of edges per node is indeterminate. You can probably filter out a significant number of candidates immediately by marking their connections as you go. I can not think of a fast algorithm to do this at the moment, but I will revisit this question when I do.